# In OpenGL ES what is an "external image"? Why do we need GL_OES_EGL_image_external?

Tags: opengl-es

I am reading through spec for [external images](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt). It says:

> This extension provides a mechanism for creating EGLImage texture targets
> from EGLImages.  This extension defines a new texture target,
> TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES.

I have done my best but I can't find out what an "external image is".  This extension, and many of the related extension specs, reference "EGLImages" and similar things but I can't figure out what they are.

Why do I need this?
Typically to create an image I load a file from disk.  I believe that is "external".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865037/whats-the-difference-between-gl-texture-2d-and-gl-texture-external-oes/53865578) basically says it is an image not created by the graphics driver but wouldn't mean virtually all images ever created would be EGLImages or "external images"?  When using OpenGL I don't remember having to worry about if my image was external or not.

Can somebody explain what an "External" image is, why it is needed (mainly I see this w/r/t OpenGL ES) and why these extensions are needed?  Frankly I am not sure what an "EGL Image" is either, or why they make a distinction.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what EGL is? "*This question basically says it is an image created by the graphics driver*" Actually, it says the exact opposite of that. Though really, it shouldn't say "graphics driver"; it should say "OpenGL ES".

Comment: Q. Do you know what EGL is? Answer: No.
It seems like yet another Khronos API that I have to get familiar with (but probably never fully understand) to draw pixels on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer.

An external image AKA external texture is typically used to supply frames from an image stream (e.g. camera preview, decoded video) as OpenGL textures. Such frames usually have special color encodings and memory layouts (e.g. multi-plane YUV). The extension mentioned above allows sampling such images as if they were regular OpenGL textures (with a few limitations).